# My nav is not going in my head

Tags: html, css

The title says it all, my navigations is not staying in my header. I have ran css validator to make sure my css is correct, and it still does not seem to be functioning as intended. Here is my code, and thanks in advance to anyone that helps me. (Ps. If there are any tools that can help me find issues like this one please do let me know.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<Header>
    <img id="logo" src="img/logo/caseywoelfle.com.svg" alt="Logo"/>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">about me</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.html">blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</Header>

<div id="homepage">

    <div id="banner">

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>

/* Header: */
header {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-89deg, #4ABCD3 0%, #0D0C0C 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-89deg, #4ABCD3 0%, #0D0C0C 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-89deg, #4ABCD3 0%, #0D0C0C 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-179deg, #4ABCD3 0%, #0D0C0C 100%); }
  header #logo {
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 112px;
    height: 100%; }
  header nav {
    width: 448px; }
    header nav ul li {
      display: inline;
      list-style: none; }
      header nav ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: Helvetica;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #823;
        line-height: 24px;
        /* Nav Text Styles */ }

#homepage #banner {
  border-radius: 29px;
  /* banner background styles */
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-89deg, #4ABCD3 0%, #000000 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-89deg, #4ABCD3 0%, #000000 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-89deg, #4ABCD3 0%, #000000 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-179deg, #4ABCD3 0%, #000000 100%); }

footer {
  border-radius: 22px;
  /* footer background styles */
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-89deg, #378797 0%, #000000 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-89deg, #378797 0%, #000000 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-89deg, #378797 0%, #000000 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-179deg, #378797 0%, #000000 100%); }

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

Comment: And what are the CSS rules in those stylsheets relevant to the header?

Comment: Nice question title ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `display: inline-block;` to both logo and navigation bar.

```
header #logo, header nav {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wnr29xe4/

Comment: Why does it not work with inline alone? Is their a reason for that?

Comment: Inline should also work if you set it to both `nav` and `nav > ul` `block` elements.

Answer (score 0):

In your header is logo with the header's height and nav is underneath.

You can float both:

```
#logo {float: left;}
nav {float: right} /* or left */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cd0oopfv/

Navigation `is` in your header, headers height is `logo + nav`. But there is no space for nav. `Nav` is block element and if you want to have one block near by another one, you have to float them.

Answer (score 0):

By default `nav` element is block-level element. It means that it takes as much space as possible making  it render on the next line. Possible solution is to make it `display: inline-block`:

```
header nav {
    width: 448px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

#### Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jbo80166/

Answer (score 0):

here i altered the logo and th nav style by adding some margins and float

```
 /* Header: */
header {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-89deg, #4ABCD3 0%, #0D0C0C 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-89deg, #4ABCD3 0%, #0D0C0C 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-89deg, #4ABCD3 0%, #0D0C0C 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-179deg, #4ABCD3 0%, #0D0C0C 100%); }
  header #logo {
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 112px;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
  }
  header nav {
    width: 600px;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 60px;
  }
    header nav ul li {
      display: inline;
      list-style: none;
      margin-left: 20px;
    }
      header nav ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: Helvetica;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #823;
        line-height: 24px;
        /* Nav Text Styles */ }

#homepage #banner {
  border-radius: 29px;
  /* banner background styles */
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-89deg, #4ABCD3 0%, #000000 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-89deg, #4ABCD3 0%, #000000 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-89deg, #4ABCD3 0%, #000000 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-179deg, #4ABCD3 0%, #000000 100%); }

footer {
  border-radius: 22px;
  /* footer background styles */
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-89deg, #378797 0%, #000000 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-89deg, #378797 0%, #000000 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-89deg, #378797 0%, #000000 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(-179deg, #378797 0%, #000000 100%); }
```